How to deploy to Cloud Run after Cloud Build (triggered from Github)?
I've been using Cloud Run for a while by using the basic "deploy from source" approach where the build & deploy is under the hood.
Now I need to build and deploy a multi-container service (sidecars). So far I have Cloud Build working and being triggered by a push to Github.
Where I'm confused is how to deploy the resulting containers to Cloud Run.  I have a service.yaml file but it references specific images and I don't see any way to indicate the newest version of an image. So from what I can tell, I'd have to manually update the service.yaml every time and then re-deploy?
While looking for answers, I found Building and deploying a container which seems to automate the updating of the service name ("The use of the $COMMIT_SHA substitution variable is populated by Cloud Build when triggered from a Git repository"), but it doesn't look like it's intended for multi-container services.
Tt makes no sense that I'd have to update service.yaml manually or write my own script to find the exact image names and substitute them in the yaml, but I can't find any other solution.
I must be missing something?

I've not done exactly this but I'm familiar with the components. I think it is reasonable to revise the service.yaml before Cloud Run deployment. This is a common pattern with e.g. Kubernetes and other technologies that use YAML (JSON) for configuration. You could sed the config file or you could use a YAML specific tool (like yq), Jsonnet or kustomize to make this more programmatic. If the service.yaml is checked-in to source control, you get the added benefit of tracking state through it too.

@DazWilkin has the right answer. Share your service.yaml or other piece of code and your issues if you need more help from us

OK. So I didn't miss anything.  Not great IMHO, but ¯_(ツ)_/¯
@DazWilkin - not sure what you mean by "If the service.yaml is checked-in to source control, you get the added benefit of tracking state through it" - can you elaborate?

Why "Not great"? YAML is imperfect but it perfectly represents the state of a Cloud Run service. You can check the YAML into source control and manage it like any other asset. If you use a templating solution or even a tool like Pulumi, you can increase the level of abstration. You would have a history of container images in Artifact Registry and a history of the Cloud Run service template|code allowing you to recreate the system's state at any point.

Interesting point about the history of the template. "Not great" is mainly referring to how I can automatically build my containers simply by pushing a tag to github and then the final deployment step is left as an exercise for the user! Deploying after a build isn't exactly an unusual thing to do.
